# The diagonal is not contained in $\mathscr A\times \mathscr A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

This is a prelim problem I ran across: suppose $(X,\mathscr A)$ is a measurable space, and $|X|>\mathfrak{c}.$ Then, $D=\left \{ (x,x):x\in X \right \}\not \in \mathscr A\times \mathscr A.$

Here is a rough sketch of my approach, which I would like to make rigorous:

First note that if we take the collection $\mathscr C$ of subsets of $D$, that have the form $A\times A:A\in \mathscr A$, then, there is a sequence $\left \{ A_n\times A_n \right \}$ such that $D\in \sigma (\left \{ A_n\times A_n \right \}).$ This follows by considering the union $\mathscr B$ of the sigma algebras generated by the collection of countable families from $\mathscr C$ and showing that $\mathscr B$ is a sigma algebra that satisfies $\mathscr C\subseteq \mathscr B\subseteq \sigma (\mathscr C).$

The idea now is to get a contradiction by injecting $D$ into $\left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{\mathbb N}.\ $ So, define a map $(x,x)\mapsto \left \{ \chi_{A_n}(x) \right \}_n\ $ and suppose that $x$ and $x'$ both belong to exactly the same $A_n.$  I want to conclude from this that the sections $D_x$ and $D_{x'}$ are the same, which would in turn imply that the map is injective.

Is my approach workable? If so, can you provide hints on how to make it rigorous?

Comment: I guess a strictly increasing union of $\sigma$-algebras is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @AndréCaldas See my edit.

Comment: @AndréCaldas. It can fail to be. If $S(a)=P(a)$ (the power set of $a$) for $a\in k$, where $k$ is a singular cardinal ordinal with $cf(k)=\aleph_0$ then  $k$  is the  union of a countable   subset of $\cup_{a\in k}S(a)$ but $k\not \in \cup_{a\in K}S(a).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet; I am claiming something different, namely that if you take a collection of subsets $\mathscr C$ of a set $X$ then for each $A\in \sigma (\mathscr C)$ there is a countable subfamily $\mathscr C_0$ of $\mathscr C$ such that $A\in \sigma (\mathscr C_0)$. I am pretty sure this is correct.

Comment: I was just responding to the comment from Andre Caldas. It doesn't seem to have any bearing on your Q.... In your Q what is the def'n of a section $D_x$?

Comment: you might be interested in the first answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20919/polish-spaces-in-probability

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $D_x=\left \{ y:(x,y)\in D \right \}$ which of course in this case, is just equal to $x$.

Comment: @nobody: yes, that's what I was after. Very nice proof of a more general claim. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that your family $\mathscr{C}$ is just the singletons from $D$. How do you relate $\mathscr{A} \times \mathscr{A}$ and $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$? Because whatever $\mathscr{A}$ is... as long as it contains the singletons, $\mathscr{C}$ will me the same thing: the diagonal singletons.